# How do I get data passed back in the Response using AJAX Jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, post

Here's my POST:

```
$("#checkin-button").click(function() { 
  var mid = $("input#mid").val();
  var dataString = 'mid='+mid;  
  $.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "/game-checkin",  
    data: dataString,  
    success: function() {  
      $('#checkin-form').html("<div id='message'></div>");  
      $('#message').html("<h2>You are checked in!</h2>");  
    }  
  });  
return false;
});
```

I am sending back a JSON string and want to use it in my Django template.  How do I capture that response for display in the template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

> success(data, textStatus,
>   XMLHttpRequest)Function
>
> A function to be called if the request
>   succeeds. The function gets passed
>   three arguments: ***The data returned
>   from the server,*** formatted according
>   to the 'dataType' parameter; a string
>   describing the status; and the
>   XMLHttpRequest object (available as of
>   jQuery 1.4). This is an Ajax Event.

I think you'll have to use [parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) to convert it.

Comment: You can avoid needing to parse JSON in jquery if you use simplejson.dumps(object) to return json, and then set the content-type header to "application/json".

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this :

```
$.post("/game-checkin", {mid: mid }, function(data){
  //response in json format. Example: data.something
}, "json");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function as callback:

```
success: function(response) {
    alert(response);
}
```

The response will be what your server returns, but as text. If you have to use that JSON effectively in Javascript you have to use the eval() function like this: eval('(' + response ')'); and it will evaluate the JSON expression so you can assign it to an object like this:

```
success: function(response) {
    var responseObj = eval('(' + response + ')');
    // use responseObj here
}
```

I don't know about Django, but this is how you get the response and evaluate it as JSON.

Comment: So response will be the JSON?  Will that be available in my template as the variable "response"?

Comment: No need to `eval` the response. jQuery can do the conversion for you - see CronosS's answer.